# Assign entire file to a var as a string using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to assign the contents of an xml file to a var, like so:

```
var testing = $.load('xx.xml');
$('#display').text(testing);
```

but it's not working. I tried the ".load" function as suggested in:

[How to assign file contents into a Javascript var](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3875833/how-to-assign-file-contents-into-a-javascript-var)

and I had a look at the page they suggest form the jquery website, but I can't find something specific to assigning the contents of the .xml file to the var as a string.

I appreciate this is probably very obvious & I am arguably being lazy, but I have been trying random things for a while & cannot figure this out.

Thanks

EDIT! I was loading up the contents inside the load function, i didn't mean this, it's now edited.

Comment: As Alex R. said, text is only for chars, not HTML. Also, why would you load the var up inside the call?

Comment: Whoops, that was a school boy error, I pasted fronm an older version, code changed.

Comment: @MarcoJohannesen, it actually won't work, so I had to retract my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, `$.load` isn't a defined function in the latest jQuery source, nor is it documented on the jQuery site.

Secondly, assuming you haven't modified jQuery's global AJAX settings, `jQuery.fn.load` and other request functions will be asynchronous, so you can't just assign the result to a variable because the function returns before the request has completed.  You need to use callback handlers.

Try using `$.ajax` with a callback function instead:

```
var testing;
$.ajax('xx.xml', {
    dataType: 'text',
    success: function (data) {
        testing = data;
        $('#display').text(testing);
    }
});
```

Since you want the data as text and the file appears to be XML, we're using `dataType` to tell jQuery to return the data as a string.

Comment: When I do this and do `alert(testing)` it returns *Object[XML Object]*.  Why does it do that, and how do I get just a nice string?

Answer (score 1):

There is no `$.load` function. What you probably want is [`jQuery.get`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/):

```
var xml;
$.get("xx.xml", function(data) {
    xml = data;
});
```

As the file is retreived asynchronously, you need to assign the result to the variable inside the callback, which is executed when the request returns successfully. Note however that if you try and run code that depends on `xml` after the `.get` call, `xml` is going to be undefined because the callback won't have run yet. For example:

```
var xml;
$.get("xx.xml", function(data) {
    xml = data;
    //Do stuff with data here
});
console.log(xml); //Most likely undefined because asynchronous call has not completed
```

If you are trying to insert the results into a DOM element, then you can use the [`.load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) *method*:

```
$("#someElem").load("xx.xml");
```

Comment: I wasn't trying to insert it into a DOM element, well, I am but this is not the main thing I am trying to achieve, that was just to prove it had been loaded.

Comment: Then just use the first example in my answer.

Comment: So woudl something like this would not work:
`var xml;
$.get("xx.xml", function(data) {
    xml = data;
});
$('#somewhere').html(xml)`
Since it is called after the variable is assigned, i.e. after the get call

Comment: No, because `xml` will be `undefined` because the asynchronous call won't have completed. You'll have to put the `$("#somewhere").html(xml)` line inside the callback. See my edit.

Comment: I see. Is there any way to force the .get call to get the file and assign contents to a variable, and then later use that variable in another function (other than by putting the other function inside the callback of course)

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying to get an xml from your server using ajax, you may try something like this -

```
function getXml()
{
    var contents;
    $.ajax({ url :'/website/method', type: 'GET', dataType :'xml', async : false, 
     cache : true, success : function(myXml){
       contents = myXml;
    }
    });     

    return contents;
}
```

Comment: Using this, a call to `getXml()` would return `undefined` because the `return contents;` line will run before the AJAX call has completed.

Comment: @James: saarthak specifically sets `async: false` in the sample code, so this should actually work as expected.  However, it's generally a bad idea to use synchronous requests - they lock up the UI preventing the user from interacting with the page and the MDN site suggests that they are prone to memory leaks.

Comment: @AndyE - Oh yeah, I missed that bit! Sorry saarthak.